# Sorting data in DynamoDB based on a changing value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table structure consisting of cities and comments. I need to get all comments related to a city. I have made my primary key for comments the name of the city. Now when I query my table I can get all the comments related to the city but I need them in order of votes for that comment. the votes value are constantly changing. I have considered adding ordered by to my query or adding vote as a range key and deleting are re-adding the recored every time the votes changes. These solutions don't seam that efficient and was wondering if there is a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy thing you could do is to use a [local secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) - this DynamoDB feature can create a second table whose hash key is the same (the city name), but the sort key is the number of votes - which remains just an ordinary attribute in your original table. DynamoDB will automatically - and consistently - take care of the second table for you as you modify the first one.

Using a LSI is easier than coding the extra deletion and addition, and more efficient in the sense of less network activity and client work - but may not be significantly cheaper in Amazon bills, because DynamoDB charges you extra for that LSI work.